# sending data to telegraf from windows git bash

Tags: telegraf

How exactly can I send data to telegraf from windows command prompt / git bash?

I'm trying to send data in unix bash to telegraf.

In bash I do:

```
echo -e "my_db,owner=me,field=value" | nc -u4 -w1 my.telefra.host.com 1231;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [telegraf exec input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/exec).
It allows you to execute any sort of command, including powershell, cmd, git bash etc. For instance, if I want to run powershell command,

```
commands = ["powershell -command <command>"]
```

Same can be done for git bash,

```
commands = ["<path>\bash.exe <command>"]
```